# Can I attach a TDA7318 running at 9 volts Vcc through I²C directly to a Pi 3B?

Tags: i2c

I've got a [TDA7318](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000150.pdf) audio mixer chip controlled via I²C interface to be attached to my Pi 3B. The chip requires 9 V power for its operation amplifier circuitry. The datasheet of the chip does not specify the expected level of the I²C signals arriving from the master (= the Pi), whereas the Pi uses +3.3 V (high).

So: Are the different voltages problematic resp. may the 3.3 volts be not high enough for the mixer to detect a logical 1?

Comment: It is unrealistic to expect people to download a data sheet to solve your problems. **You** should extract the relevant portions and include in your Question.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet says 3V is enough for high.

Comment: The response signal of the TDA will be at the same level as the signal coming from the Pi (3.3 V) and not at 9 V, right?

Comment: As long as there are no pull ups apart from the Pi ones.

Comment: No, there are none on the chip.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a level converter.

With a 5V device you can (usually) directly connect **provided there are no external pullup** but the logic levels would most likely be too low for a 9V device.

Comment: There are no pull-ups on the slave (= chip) side.